# How can I characterize this voltage source?

Tags: batteries, characterization

This is my first attempt at trying to characterize a voltage source.

---

The voltage source is a 99.8% magnesium rod (10mm diam., 160mm in length) its length wrapped by paper 1mm in thickness then its length once again wound with 4 meters 3k carbon filament. Its electrolyte is soil (moisture level: damp to touch) with heavy clay content, ph ~7. It is placed so that it stands with its full length vertically in the soil with only the top 2mm above the soil. Both its anode and cathode attached to 12 AWG insulated wire 100mm in length.

---

Here has been my process thus far:

1. Shorting the device and reading the current. Using the ammeter setting on my multimeter which has separate settings for μA, mA, and A. Set to μA. Positive lead attached to cathode, negative lead to anode.

Result: 0.00 (possibly not sensitive enough?)

*Edit: A friend has suggested this may be a high impedance source. I wonder how I might test that.

2. Finding the open circuit voltage. Using the voltage detting with the multimeter still attached as in step 1 but leads are separated so as not to touch.

Result: 1.327V and slowly rising [over an hour this will rise to 1.68V.]

3. Attach various resistances and measure voltage. Voltage setting with multimeter still attached as above. The resistor is measured first separately, then placed in between the multimeter leads. (Voltage shorted to 1.327V prior to each test.) The resistors are carbon film except in the one instance mentioned. The voltage source has an unstable frequency measured on an oscilloscope between 2Hz and 10Hz.

Results: (that make no sense!)

- 2.3 ohms, 1.4mV
- 5.1 ohms, 6.7mV
- 21.9 ohms, 14.5mV
- 99.5 ohms, 127mV rises at rate of 2mv/s. (127mV is initial reading)
- 150.9 ohms (wirewound resistor), 182mV*
- 325.8 ohms, 347mV rising

*The 150.9 resistor started out at 110mV and rose at a rate of approx. 0.5mV/s for over 7 minutes, at which point I took the 182mV reading and stopped. While I recorded the readings and looked up, it had already reached into 188mV and still was rising.

I didn't know what other tests to perform so I thought I'd use my multimeter and do a few other tests.

4. Using the diode setting (to see how it would charge).

Result: 1.715 rising rapidly to 2.0 at which point my multimeter went to O/L. I quickly went to μA setting and shorted the leads. still 0μA

Back at voltage setting.

Result: now at around 1.71V and slowly dropping until it reaches 1.35V over twenty seconds

5. Use diode setting to 'recharge' to 2.0V. Return to voltage setting and short.

Result: Immediate discharge from 1.98V to 1.35V

6. Capacitance detting

Result: Multimeter read 0.000 [indicating seeking] then eventually O/L [too large] maximum 2mF for this multimeter.

7. AC setting: 1mV

Perhaps this is enough data to characterize the voltage source. What other info might be useful to help characterize it?

Comment: As the DC conditions will cause polarisation in the electrolyte and the soil, you can expect voltage readings to be time varying garbage, as you've found. That's why moisture meters and the like use external AC excitation of the electrodes.

Comment: @Neil_UK Ok, that's useful to a degree, I can possibly ignore 'time varying garbage' and stick mainly to initial readings. Is that the suggestion, then?

Comment: the problem with that is making sure the electrodes, and the soil, start each 'initial reading' in the same chemical state - cleanliness, ionic concentrations, a non-starter really. Persist in your measurements for long enough to convince yourself that  your setup isn't really repeatable or controllable. Then if you want to measure the characteristics of the soil, use two identical electrodes, inert as possible, and make AC conductivity measurements. If you want to characterise a battery with carbon and magnesium electrodes, make a repeatable electrolyte from simple chemicals.

Comment: @Neil_UK 'make AC conductivity measurements' Are you saying here, to check pH, moisture with AC equipment first, then use this data in the calculations to modify the measurements I make at that point? That makes sense - then the characterization is repeatable in a changing environment. On the other hand I would have to create a stable environment and take the measurements in there instead. This latter suggestion isn't workable for reasons I'm unable to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically with a battery what you have is a voltage and a series resistance, knowing the open circuit voltage and load resistance you can use Ohm's Law to find the source resistance.

You can calculate it with this formula:

```
Rsource = (Vsource - Vload)/(Vload/Rload)
```

So with the 325.8 ohm resistor it's

```
Rsource = (1.327 - 0.347)/(0.347/325.8) = 920.1268 ohms.
```

If you calculate it with the values you got for the 27.9 ohm resistor it will be around 1982 ohms. So clearly it's not operating in a linear fashion.

Putting it in a table with with all of your readings yields this:
[image: battery test values]

It's hard to tell why the values are all over the place, I'm not sure what a makeshift battery buried in the ground is supposed to do, it's never really come up before. You could do more testing, try to get more accurate values and use a wider range of loads, and then put your results in a spreadsheet using the formula to calculate the values.

Comment: Thanks for the formula for source resistance! One commentor below suggested reasons for the many various results. I have a few theories on top of his. I've actually been able to use 6 of these to self-power a boost circuit and get over 12V @ 30mA (pulsed @ 250KHz). I have bigger plans, but I want to characterize it, and calculate everything before building circuit #2

Comment: Ah... just realized the load currents came out wrong when I changed the formula from amps to milliamps. I'll fix it.

Comment: By the way, isn't Iload actually divided by 1000? so, 608 uA, 1.313 mA, etc? As much as it would be wonderful to get over an Amp on such a small cell... ;) What are we doing today, Brain? The same as we do everyday! Powering the World!

Comment: @RobMcN Fixed. I multiplied by 1000 to get mA and it was okay until I changed the load voltages to mV, and it recalculated things. Oopsie.

Answer (score 1):

> Finding the Open Voltage [...] with the multimeter

That's anything but an "open voltage" for a source like that. It's loaded down with a 10MOhm input impedance of the multimeter. You need very high impedance "electrometer" buffer/amplifier to accurately measure the voltage, or a voltmeter with a high impedance measurement mode. The input impedance of the "meter" must be at least 3 orders of magnitude higher than what a simple multimeter gives you, and ideally you'd want it 5-6 orders of magnitude higher. The conductance between the inputs would be in the 1pS-100pS ballpark. And you need tools and techniques to reliably measure it, too, otherwise you're just guessing.

At such impedances, the insulation conductance of the input wires and the bulk conductance of the PCB matters as well, especially if the environment has high humidity or condensation. PTFE or ETFE (Tefzel) insulated input wires are ideal, and the input nodes need either very good PCB guarding and very clean PCB, or PTFE/glass/ceramic insulated stand-offs for high impedance nodes. Meticulous attention to cleanliness and ionic decontamination of the area around high impedance nodes by the preamplifier chip is essential.

> Shorting the device and reading the current. Using the ammeter setting on my multimeter which has separate settings for μA, mA, and A. Set to μA.

No need for that. You already measured the current. The shunt resistor was the multimeter's volts mode input impedance of 10MOhm:

$$ {1.6{\,\rm V} \over 10{\,\rm M}\Omega} = 0.16\,\mu{\rm A} $$

The current at 0V won't be much higher, but feel free to shunt the voltmeter with a 1MOhm resistor and redo the measurement at 1/11th of the voltage (approximately).

For the sources you describe, 1uS load conductance (1MOhm between leads) is just as good as a dead short.

Comment: Do you have a thought on a buffer amplifier circuit I can build for this? I have no problem building the circuit. I would guess that an opamp would be the best choice for the amplifier over a common base transistor.

Comment: @RobMcN Google electrometer amplifiers. You'd be using a FET-input amplifier designed for such applications (on the order of 1TOhm differential input impedance, fA bias currents) and will have to get the supplies needed to remove ionic contamination, as well as some known-good test equipment that you can use to actually measure the leakage currents in your circuitry and wiring. You'll need a picoammeter and look at Fluke's application notes about ultra-low current measurement. They explain what's necessary for reliable results. You'll need to characterize your preamp before you can trust it.